# unexpected identifier on a mysql query in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have the following code:

```
 connection.query("SELECT * FROM accounts_data WHERE new_username LIKE '%" + username + "%';", function (error, results, fields) {

});
```

and I am getting the following error

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts_data` WHERE `new_username` LIKE '%preloved_bys%'
                               ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1054:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)
```

what is wrong with the query? when i execute it via phpmyadmin it works just fine

Comment: Can you show more code?

Comment: Did you try with backticks ` ?

Comment: Could you please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example including version of installed deps ? Thank you

Comment: Can you provide `npm view mysql version`, `npm -v`, `node -v`?

Comment: Do you have any other code? If you have, does the other code(s) execute without error? I'm guessing this is a part of some other codes.. if so, could you please post the whole code so that we can see the bigger picture?

Comment: I think this is coming from the node version you're using, you might have to rollback to a more stable version. Which one are you using?

Comment: 1. Pay attention that the error message is produced by node.js, not by MySQL. I.e. the query even was not sent to MySQL, the error was detected before. 2. Pay attention that object names are not enclosed into backticks in query text in code but are enclosed in the error message. Totally: looks like node.js parser issue.

Answer (score 2):

i get success with do following :

```
var value = 'sc188203395acc255';
connection.query('SELECT * from emp where empid like ?', '%' + value + '%', ...)
```

Turn on debugging in the driver (pass `debug:true` as argument to `mysql.createConnection` ), it doesn't escape the percent sign

One More Way to Slove this Error :

```
"SELECT * FROM emp WHERE name empid " + connection.escape('%'+value+'%')
```

use connection.escape alternate way to do same things

One More Way to Solve this Error :

reinstall module on your project because sometimes error can be solved by reinstalling it

delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and last run `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is nothing wrong with the following code. 
but fyi, `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` occurs due to some reasons, mentioned below:

1. SQL is `case-sensitive` language when you pass any parameter into it like `'new_username'`. Recheck it should be correct.
2. use of unwanted special character like `' or "`
3. using an `invalid identifier`.

   Give a try with the following code:

```
    let str = '%'+username+'%';
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM accouts_data WHERE new_username LIKE ?";
        
        connection.query(sql, str, function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err
        });
```

Just in case, if it doesn't work, update your node_modules with `npm install`. Or just remove version number from all modules in `package.json` file like `"mysql": "^2.18.1"` just remove `^2.18.1`. and Then, Run:

```
npm install
```

It'll update every module with their latest version automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with the query, tested it with [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) and [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) and it gives the expected result.
It must be related to nodejs, try removing `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json`  file and run `npm install`

Comment: yes this is a js issue, i am aware .. how does removing node_modules help though ?

Comment: I had an issue related to `internal/modules/cjs/loader.js` not with mysql though, reinstalling my app dependencies helped

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use proper escaping provided by `mysql` lib:

```
connection.query(
  "SELECT * FROM accounts_data WHERE new_username LIKE ?; ",
  ['%' + username + '%'],
  function (error, results, fields) { ... }
);
```

Also check your `mysql` version both on client (npm package) and server side.

For debugging, I often use `console.log(connection.format(query, values));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat 
example

```
connection.query("SELECT * FROM accounts_data WHERE new_username LIKE concat('%',?,'%');", [username],(error, results, fields)=>{console.log(result)})
```